# Django DRF - serializing foreign key relationship in a linear form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF to power up my Django REST api. Consider the following model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = CharField(...)

class Book(models.Model)
   author = ForeignKey(Ablum)
   title = CharField(...)
```

My desired output should be a linear JSON looking like this:

```
[
   {
      "name": "Jack London",
      "title": "White fang"
   }
   {
     "name": "Jack London",
     "title": "Martin Iden"
   }
   {
      "name": "Charles Dickens",
      "title": "David Coperfield" 
    }
    {
      "name": "Charles Dickens",
      "title": "Oliver Twist"
    }
]
```

I accomplished the result using the corresponding serializers

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.CharField(source='album.author')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        depth = 1
        fields = ('author', 'title ')
```

...but the problem is that this solution is very dirty in terms of DRYness. Every time I add new field to Author, I would like it to appear in Book as well. Is there any way to tell Django to include all fields of the related model ? Or

I also tried the following approach:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        author = CalendarEventSerializer(read_only = True)

        class Meta:
           model = Book
           depth = 1
           fields = ('author', 'title ')
```

but with this I ended up with nested JSON structure like this:

[
       {
          "name": "Jack London",
          "author": {...}
       },
       ...
]

which does not meet my needs. 
So, the question is: is there more DRY approach than what I did here ?

Answer (score 0):

Just write you custom `get_author` method.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, instance):
        # write whatever you want
        return author

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author', 'title ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add serializer method `get_author_name`. So you will get the data just like you wanted. add `author` field in the serializer and make it **write_only**, so that you can create and update using the same serializer

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author_name = serializers.serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author', 'author_name', 'title')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'author': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def get_auther_name(self, obj):
        return obj.auther.name
```

Your json will be

```
[
   {
      "auther_name": "Jack London",
      "title": "White fang"
   }
   {
     "auther_name": "Jack London",
     "title": "Martin Iden"
   }
   {
      "auther_name": "Charles Dickens",
      "title": "David Coperfield" 
    }
    {
      "auther_name": "Charles Dickens",
      "title": "Oliver Twist"
    }
]
```

Note: Dont override `author` filed. If so you cant use the serializer for adding or updating

**UPDATE** (Based on the comment)

If you dont want to change the result field, then use like

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    author_obj = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Author.objects.all(), required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author_obj', 'author', 'title')        

    def get_auther(self, obj):
        return obj.auther.name
```

Thus the result will be same as that you wanted. For adding or updating, provide id of the author to filed `author_obj` in the request

Comment: I forgot to mention this method in the question. No, it does not satisfy my needs either, because you change the original field name. It should be `name` instead of `author_name`

Comment: If so just rename author_name with author. And also the function. For write operation use any field and map with primarykey related field. I have updated my answer. Please check it